# How many ways are there to distribute $18$ distinguishable object into boxes?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, solution-verification, combinations

> How many ways are there to distribute $18$ distinguisable object into
>
> a-) $5$ distinguishable boxes so that the boxes have $1,2,4,5,6$ objects in them, respectively.
>
> b-) $5$ distinguishable boxes so that the boxes have $1,2,4,5,6$
> objects in them.
>
> c-) $5$ distinguishable boxes so that the boxes have $4,2,2,5,5$
> objects in them, respectively.
>
> d-) $5$ distinguishable boxes so that the boxes have $4,2,2,5,5$
> objects in them.
>
> e-) $5$ indistinguishable boxes so that the boxes have $1,2,4,5,6$
> objects in them, respectively.
>
> f-) $5$ indistinguishable boxes so that the boxes have $1,2,4,5,6$
> objects in them.
>
> g-) $5$ indistinguishable boxes so that the boxes have $4,2,2,5,5$
> objects in them, respectively.
>
> h-) $5$ indistinguishable boxes so that the boxes have $4,2,2,5,5$
> objects in them.

My attempt:

a-) $ C(18,1) \times C(17,2) \times C(15,4) \times C(11,5) \times C(6,6) $

b-) $ 5! \times (C(18,1) \times C(17,2) \times C(15,4) \times C(11,5) \times C(6,6)) $

c-)  $C(18,4) \times C(14,2) \times C(12,2) \times C(10,5) \times C(5,5) $

d-) $(\frac{5!}{2!\times 2! \times 1!})\times(C(18,4) \times C(14,2) \times C(12,2) \times C(10,5) \times C(5,5)) $

e-) I think this question is invalid , because if the boxes are indistinguishable then we cannot talk about respectivity.

f-) In this question , i firstly thought them like distinguishable boxes, after that i divide them by

$5!$ to obtain indistinguishable form such that $\frac{(C(18,1) \times C(17,2) \times C(15,4) \times C(11,5) \times C(6,6))}{5!} $

g-)I think this question is invalid, because if the boxes are indistinguishable then we cannot talk about respectivity.

h-) In this question, i firstly thought them like distinguishable boxes, after that i divide them by

$\frac{5!}{2!\times 2! \times 1!}$ such that $\frac{C(18,4) \times C(14,2) \times C(12,2) \times C(10,5) \times C(5,5)}{\frac{5!}{2!\times 2! \times 1!}} $

Is my solutions correct? If not, can you correct me, please ?

Comment: I think they are all correct.

Comment: Please remove the glaring red "hard question" from the title. (Among other things, it is not particularly true.)

Comment: Hmm I mean you should have only put the questions you had doubt in here. Right now, it feels like an exercise sheet . You may have got more answers if you had tried to be a bit more focused

Comment: what is $C(18,1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only have comments on your working for (f) and (h).

(f) The idea is to create $5$ indistinguishable heaps of $1, 2, 4, 5$ and $6$ objects and that is simply $C(18,1) \times C(17,2) \times C(15,4) \times C(11,5) \times C(6,6)$, same  as in your answer $(a)$.

(h) It is similar to (f) but we have heaps of $4, 2, 2, 5$ and $5$ objects. Now note that $C(18,4) \times C(14,2) \times C(12,2) \times C(10,5) \times C(5,5)$ will order two heaps of $2$ objects and will order two heaps of $5$ objects but we do not want that.

So the answer to this is $ \ \displaystyle \frac{1}{2 \cdot 2} \cdot C(18,4) \times C(14,2) \times C(12,2) \times C(10,5) \times C(5,5)$

Comment: look at please : https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780071315012-discrete-mathematics-and-its-applications-global-edition-7th-edition/420/exercises/28/

Comment: I solved them according to slader.com

Comment: Yes the working given there is correct. That is why in (h), you need to divide by $2! \cdot 2!$.

Comment: and similarly for (f), you either take answer of (b) and divide by $5!$ or you take (a) and in that case you do not divide by $5!$.

Comment: what i did not understand is that when they are distinguishable , we multiply them by permutation as to how many object they have.Moreover , when they are indistinguishable , we divide the result of combination by permutation. We saw it in slader and part $f$. However , in part $h$ we did not divide them by permutation. I thought that if part $d$ is true ,then part $h$ must be true ,as well

Comment: think of (d) as this - there are $5$ distinct boxes and they can be permuted in $5!$ ways but objects in two boxes with $2$ objects each are already ordered and same with two boxes with $5$ objects each. So we divide by $2! \ 2!$. For (f), we do the same division as we do not want them ordered. We also do not multiply by $5!$ as boxes are indistinguishable.

Comment: otherwise , should part $\color{blue}{h}$ have been equal to just $C(18,4) \times C(14,2) \times C(12,2) \times C(10,5)  $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124194/discussion-between-math-lover-and-leonard).

Comment: according to conversetion between you and bulbasaur , the main concept is writing $1!$ in numerator instead of writing permutation of boxes